# How to fill a web form on a page that uses JavaScript

Tags: javascript, python, html, mechanize

I'm trying to write a script that automatically fills a web form using `Mechanize`. However, the target page uses JavaScript and `Mechanize` won't find the form I need. Is there any way to get a form out of a `div` that only displays if JavaScript is enabled and fill it out?

Answer (score 2):

You can analyse the JavaScript (can you post it?) and see if you can solve the problem by scraping a different URL, or reimplementing the logic yourself in Python. If what you really need is to execute JavaScript within the DOM programmatically, try [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/), the headless web stack.